# Extrair e executar um Recurso em loop foreach c#

Tags: c#

```
private string GetDialogs()
        {
            string temp = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "dlgs.exe");

            using FileStream stream = new(temp, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read);
            byte[] bytes = Properties.Resources.GetDialogsApp();

            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            return temp;
        }

public string Dialogs => GetDialogs();
```

Eu uso o código acima instanciado. Dentro do loop eu uso o "**_app.Dialogs**" para apontar para o "dlgs,exe" e extrair textos de arquivos usando "**Process.Start**".
Mas está extraindo o .exe para cada iteração da lista de arquivos e quero evitar isso.
Se uso "**FileMode.CreateNew**" causa exceção que arquivo existe com mesmo nome.
Se uso "**FileShare.ReadWrite**" o .exe é regravado para cada iteração da lista.

Como posso declarar o Recurso para ser extraído uma vez e usado por todos os arquivos da lista?